# javascript not working in MSIE,Safari,Opera; works in FF,Chrome; how to use jQuery instead?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to writing javascript and very new to jQuery. I am trying to make these (3) images tumble across the top of the page on body load. It works ok in FF and Chrome, but not at all in MSIE, Safari and Opera. I'm not sure how to include my html or css here. Website is tumbleweedcolorado.com

This is the javaScript and the html is below.

```
 //external js file

   function slideIn(el){
         var elem = document.getElementById(el);
          elem.style.transition = "left 5.0s ease-in 0s";
           elem.style.left = "950px";
            }
    function slideOver(el){
         var elem = document.getElementById(el);
          elem.style.transition = "left 5.0s ease-in 0.7s";
           elem.style.left = "950px";
            }
    function slideRight(el){
         var elem = document.getElementById(el);
          elem.style.transition = "left 5.0s ease-in 2.5s";
           elem.style.left = "950px";
            }

    var looper;
    var degrees = 0;
    function rotateAnimation(el,speed){
    var elem = document.getElementById(el);
        if(navigator.userAgent.match("Chrome")){
        elem.style.WebkitTransform = "rotate("+degrees+"deg)";
        } else if(navigator.userAgent.match("Firefox")){
        elem.style.MozTransform = "rotate("+degrees+"deg)";
        } else if(navigator.userAgent.match("MSIE")){
        elem.style.msTransform = "rotate("+degrees+"deg)";
        } else if(navigator.userAgent.match("Opera")){
        elem.style.OTransform = "rotate("+degrees+"deg)";
        } else if(navigator.userAgent.match("Safari")){
        elem.style.AppleWebKitTransform = "rotate("+degrees+"deg)";
        } else {
        elem.style.transform = "rotate("+degrees+"deg)";
    }
    looper = setTimeout('rotateAnimation(\''+el+'\','+speed+')',speed);
    degrees++;
    if(degrees > 359){
    degrees = 1;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Don't use browser detection? The current browser versions do all support `style.transform`, **only** if that doesn't exist you need to use vendor prefixes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vendor prefixes aren't intended to be permanent, so Chrome won't always use `WebkitTransform`, for example.

You'll be better served using feature detection than browser sniffing, determining the appropriate property name by which exist:

```
if ('transform' in elem.style) {
    elem.style.transform = "rotate("+degrees+"deg)";
} else if ('webkitTransform' in elem.style) {
    elem.style.webkitTransform = "rotate("+degrees+"deg)";
} // etc.
```

But, you can also use the CSS property names with [`elem.style.setProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration):

```
function rotateAnimation(el,speed){
    var elem = document.getElementById(el);
    var transform = "rotate("+degrees+"deg)";

    elem.style.setProperty('-webkit-transform', transform);
    elem.style.setProperty('-moz-transform', transform);
    elem.style.setProperty('-ms-transform', transform);
    elem.style.setProperty('-o-transform', transform);
    elem.style.setProperty('transform', transform);

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I tried (feature detection) suggestion but results were the same. Then I tried the CSS setProperty suggestion, and no rotation at all. Even if I could just get IE and Safari (my client's browser) working, it would be great. Any other suggestions?